# Postgres: prioritize main application over background celery jobs

Tags: django, postgresql, celery

I'm working on django application that uses celery for background tasks.
Those tasks parse users uploads, make some api calls and then write results to postgres database. Celery is running with 20 workers. 
Sometimes, when user uploads bigger file (like 200k records to process), main site becomes unavailable because database is overloaded by celery task queries.

Do you know how can I solve it?

On one hand - I can just reduce number of celery workers and make parsing slower, on the other hand - it would be great to make use of free resources, when there's not a lot of people using main site.

I'm not very experienced with postgres configuration, so i'm not sure if I need to modify postgres or celery configuration, or even modify the tasks.

Please, tell me how you would solve it or maybe tell me in which direction I should read documentation.

Thank you

Comment: OK first you need to sleuth out exactly what part of your DB server is being overloaded when this happens. iostat, vmstat, top, iotop, htop, sysstat/par are all good tools here. There's a different approach to fix an onverloaded db server depending on what's being overloaded.

Answer (score 0):

More information would be needed to give a better answer, but candidate things to look into include:

- Avoiding unnecessarily locks in your celery tasks if possible. (It might not be…)
- Running a pre-flight check before launching a celery task, and sleeping if too much is going on.

Regarding the second point, you can obtain lists by querying the catalog:

```
select count(*) from pg_stat_activity;
select count(*) from pg_locks;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is not point in having so much workers that when all are active the database is overloaded, so unless you can find another optimization, reducing the number of workers is a good idea. This will not make things slower when few people are using the site, since not all workers are used then (to simplify, otherwise, the db would be overloaded).

Maybe your tasks could be split in oder to have a better granularity when configuring your workers. Let's say for example you can split a task into three parts:

- parsing - long and CPU intensive
- api calls - long and lower load
- db update - quick

Then you could dedicate a Celery queue to each task type, and configure a different number of workers on each queue. For example, dedicate more workers to I/O bound API calls, and use only one or two workers for the DB updates.

That may not solve your problem if the bottleneck is in the db, but a least you will have a better view of the issue, and you will have reduced the DB task to the smallest extend possible (hence, no lock during the parsing for exemple).